# Why do string functions have some parameters as const char *( pointers to constant characters)?

Tags: c

Strings(character arrays) can be modified in C but string literals can't be modified. But why do string functions like strlen(const char *str) have a pointer to a constant characters?

Comment: Note that `const` and "constant" are actually two different things in C. `const` means read-only. A "constant" expression is one that can be evaluated at compile time. For example: `const int r = rand();`; the value of `r` clearly is not *constant*, but it can't legally be changed after initialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const T* p` means that the memory that `p` points to cannot be modified *via* the variable `p`.  It represents a promise that `p` will not be used to modify the memory pointed to.  It does not mean that the `p` points to memory that can never be modified.

It's always safe to convert from a `T*` to a `const T*`:

```
T value;
T* q = &value; // Not const.
const T* p = q; // No cast necessary.
p = &value; // No cast necessary here either.
```

Consequently, if a string function does not mutate its arguments, there is no harm in declaring its parameters as `const char*`:

```
const char* s = "string literal";
strlen(s); // This is legal.

char buf[] = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' };
strlen(buf); // This is legal too.
```

However, if the parameter instead were declared as just `char*`, then you would *not* be able to pass `const char*` to it.

```
 void foo(char* s);

 const char* s = "string literal";
 foo(s); // This will fail to compile.
```

Therefore it is advantageous to remember to qualify pointer arguments with `const` if possible, and doing so documents that the function promises not to mutate the pointee.

Answer (score 3):

Because they do not modify (and do not need to modify) their argument strings. That's what that `const` means.

If `strlen`'s argument were declared as `char *` (no `const`), you wouldn't be able to use `strlen` to determine the length of a constant string. For example

```
size_t my_own_strlen(char *str) { /* whatever */ }

const char hello[] = "Hello";

size_t l1 = my_own_strlen(hello); // Error: cannot convert `const char *` to `char *`
size_t l2 = strlen(hello);        // OK
```

Declaring that argument as `const char *` makes `strlen` applicable to both constant and non-constant strings.

Answer (score 1):

It simply means that the function will not modify the data the pointer points to. Gives you some type safety and the compiler opportunity to optimise.

Comment: It doesn't give any optimization opportunity, it's all about avoiding unintended writes via type safety

Comment: Well, it could help the compiler infer that the function is pure. There are plenty of optimisation opportunities for that. For instance, it could be used by the compiler to change the function call to a constant or perform some sort of CSE

Comment: The function could still cast away const and modify the pointed-to object  (which is not undefined behaviour if the object is not actually const), so the calling code cannot assume that the function does not change the object.

Answer (score 0):

`strlen(const char *str)` have a pointer to constant characters because it'll take the input `*str` as **read-only** string, and then perform the calculation and return the value without modifying the original string because it in order to count the length of the string, it doesn't need to modify the string in the memory.